# Write the expression so that the variable is only presented once and the exponents are positive.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is this problem 
$\frac{10x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{15x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4}}}$
and i know that the answer is 
$\frac{2x^{\frac{5}{6}}}{3y}$
but i cant find the logic of how is solved, Where do the coefficients come from?
I understand that fractions are the result of multiplication of expressions, but I do not understand how all come together.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Just remember that 
$$
\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}
$$

Comment: Based on your original expression, an equivalent expression as an answer would be something like $\frac{2x^{\frac{5}{6}}}{3xy}$, i.e., you may be missing the $x$ factor in the denominator. Alternatively, if the factor of $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in the denominator of the problem is supposed to be $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ instead, then the answer would be correct. Another possibility is the answer exponent of $x$ should be $\frac{-1}{6}$. Considering your title, it's seems one of the latter $2$ cases are more likely.  Nonetheless, please check on this & correct the question text accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. For solving it, note that $x^{-r}x^r = 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you so much!, i will try to solve it that way, i know that this is simple stuff but i just started to try to understand math and get lost very easy.

Comment: @DerekBeltran You're welcome for my help. As for trying to solving the problem as I suggest, you may wish to do that before looking at my answer as I show how to get the answer using that suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that $\frac {a^{k}}{a^{m}} = a^{k-m}$.

So.....

$\frac{10x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{15x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4}}}=\frac {10}{15}\cdot \frac {x^{\frac 13}}{x^{-\frac 12}}\cdot \frac {y^{-\frac 14}}{y^{\frac 34}}=$

$\frac 23\cdot x^{\frac 13 -(-\frac 12)}\cdot y^{-\frac 14-\frac 34}=$

$\frac 23\cdot x^{\frac 56}\cdot y^{-1}=$

$\frac 23 \cdot x^{\frac 56}\cdot \frac 1y=$

$\frac {2x^{\frac 56}}{3y}$

Answer (score 0):

You need to know some basic [Exponential identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents) :

$$\frac{10x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{15x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$
$$=\frac{10}{15} \times \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^{-1/2}} \times \frac{y^{-1/4}}{y^{3/4}}$$

Using $\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$

$$=\frac{5 \times 2}{5 \times 3} \times x^{1/3+1/2} \times y^{-1/4-3/4}$$

$$=\frac{2}{3} \times x^{5/6} \times y^{-1}$$
$$=\frac{5 \times 2}{5 \times 3} \times x^{5/6} \times y^{-1}$$
$$=\frac{2x^{\frac{5}{6}}}{3y}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^{r}x^{q} = x^{r+q}$, so if $r = -q$, then $x^{-q}x^{q} = x^{-q+q} = x^{0} = 1$. Thus, you can "remove" the negative exponent factors by multiplying the numerator & denominator by the factor using the corresponding positive exponent, as shown below

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{10x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{15x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4}}} & = \frac{2(5)x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{3(5)x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4}}} \left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{4}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{4}}}\right) \\
& = \frac{2x^{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{-1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}}}{3x^{\frac{-1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}}} \\
& = \frac{2x^{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}}}{3y^{\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}}} \\
& = \frac{2x^{\frac{5}{6}}}{3y}\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$